# Using URL Link To Send Params To VB.NET App

Tags: vb.net, url, parameters, get, param

What I am looking for is using a URL link such as "MyApp://param=value" or "MyApp://mysite.com/?params=value" to open my application and read the params using GET. I do not want to use the click once method to do this, because I want the application to load up without the starting up bar at the topleft. I know it could be done but I could not find anywhere to do it at. You can see an example used over at curse.com where they use a link like "curse://curse.com/?etc=etc" to launch their app and download the item. Another example is with Ventrilo where you can use "ventrillo://etc" links to start vent and connect to a server. The reason I want this is because I plan to use it to give my customers a way to give their clients a way to connect to their servers with my software using a simple URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the question is about VB.NET, I’m assuming you are targeting Windows.

In that case, this can be done by [registering a custom URL handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) via the Windows registry.

Other operating systems have different ways of achieving this.